# Initialize static const std::map during compile time?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I have a look up table in my C++ program and for now I have to initialize it at the beginning of the program using something like this:

```
static const map<string, int> m;
m["a"] = 1;
m["b"] = 2;
...
```

I am just wondering if there is anyway I can make this initialization process happen at compile time rather than run time? I understand this has very small impact of performance to my program. I am just curious that with in the scope of current C++11/14/17 semantic it is possible or not.

Comment: Initialization will happen at runtime regardless of what you do but you can use an [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) to make it easier and more idiomatic.

Comment: Allocation of dynamic memory is one of the things not allowed in `constexpr` routines, and `std::map` can't avoid it.

Comment: `static const map<string, int> m{{"a", 1}, {"b", 2}};` but it is still at runtime.

Comment: You could use `std::array<std::pair<string, int>, xx>`, you can't use a map for `constexpr`.

Comment: You might consider `boost::hana` maps.

Comment: @bopersson While closing as duplicate is great, closing as duplicate of a wrong answer seems unwise.

Comment: @Yakk - There are several answers, some of which are correct (and more upvoted than the selected answer).

Comment: @BoPersson Sure, but cannot we find one where the checkmark isn't misplaced?  Failing that, we should make one.  A poor cannonical dupe target is poor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't initialize the `std::map` with data in compile time!

However, you can use this "fancier" initializer if you prefer, then you can have your data in a `const std::map`, in case this is what you are trying to do.

```
static const map<string, int> m = {
    { "a", 1 },
    { "b", 2 }
};
```

But AGAIN, this WILL NOT initialize the `std::map` itself in compile time. Behind the scenes, `std::map` will do the job in runtime.